# Parameters not getting loaded in run time in SSIS package

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have simple SSIS package. My source is sql command as follows:

```
  Select * from table1 where col in (select col from table2 where col3='VAL')

  For VAL I created the variable. and for subquery I created one more variable.

  Variable1=VAL

  variable2=select col from table2 where col3=Variable1
```

So my source is as follows:

```
  Select * from table1 where col in (variable2)
```

When I run the package, this is not replacing. Seems to be the Variable2 is not loading properly.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if col is the joining column between table1 and table2, you can rewrite the query as shown below:

```
SELECT      *
FROM        dbo.Table1  T1
INNER JOIN  dbo.Table2  T2
ON          T1.Col      = T2.Col
WHERE       T2.Col3     = 'VAL'
```

I assume that you are using this query in the OLE DB Source or ADO.NET Source to read it using SQL Command option.

So, put your query in a stored procedure as shown below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetData
(
    @Param1 NVARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT      T1.col
            ,   T2.col3
    FROM        dbo.Table1  T1
    INNER JOIN  dbo.Table2  T2
    ON          T1.Col      = T2.Col
    WHERE       T2.Col3     = @Param1
END
```

Create two SSIS package variables to store the stored procedure execution command and also the parameter value to be passed.

[image: Variables]

On the properties of the variable *StoredProcedure*, set the property *EvaluateAsExpression* to `True` and set the *Expression* to `"EXEC dbo.GetData '"  + @[User::Parameter] + "'"`

[image: Expression]

Use the variable `StoredProcedure` as shown below to pass it as a variable to the OLE DB Source. Whenever the value in the variable Parameter changes, the stored procedure execution command will change accordingly.

[image: OLE DB]